# arithmetic in copy command

Tags: copy, command, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to perform some transformation in the **COPY** command using below; however, getting errors like >"Function '-' not supported within COPY"

it is complaining about the arithmetic operation/minus sign in the brackets.

Thanks in advance for your comments.

```
split('lemon  orange','  ')[array_size(split('lemon  orange','  '))-1]
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you updated your question with the complete COPY command you are using

Answer (score 0):

So this can be done without the ARRAY_SIZE or subtraction (in a SELECT command)

```
SELECT
    'lemon  orange' as in_str,
    split(in_str,'  ') as s,
    s[array_size(s)-1] as last_item_a,
    reverse(in_str) as r_in_str,
    split(r_in_str, '  ') as rs,
    rs[0] as r_last_b,
    reverse(r_last_b) as last_b
    ;
```

| IN_STR | S | LAST_ITEM_A | R_IN_STR | RS | R_LAST_B | LAST_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lemon orange | [ "lemon", "orange" ] | "orange" | egnaro nomel | [ "egnaro", "nomel" ] | "egnaro" | orange |

OR in one line

```
SELECT
    'lemon  orange' as in_str,
    split(in_str,'  ')[array_size(split(in_str,'  '))-1]::text as last_a,
    reverse(split(reverse(in_str), '  ')[0]) as last
    ;
```

this time I added a `::text` to your method as the output from the prior run show double quotes in the WebUI which show it was still being treated as a VARIANT data type, which can upset other data processing functions like TO_DATA or TO_NUMBER some times.

| IN_STR | LAST_A | LAST |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lemon orange | orange | orange |

I have not checked to see if the works via a COPY.. though

```
COPY INTO @~/copy_test.csv FROM (SELECT 'lemon  orange'::text as in_str);   

CREATE TABLE copy_to_test(single_string text);

COPY INTO copy_to_test FROM (
    SELECT split($1,'  ')[array_size(split($1,'  '))-1]::text FROM @~/copy_test.csv);
    
-- 002300 (0A000): SQL Compilation error: Function '-' not supported within a COPY

COPY INTO copy_to_test FROM (
    SELECT reverse(split(reverse($1), '  ')[0]) FROM @~/copy_test.csv);
```

| file | status | rows_parsed | rows_loaded | error_limit | errors_seen | first_error | first_error_line | first_error_character | first_error_column_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| copy_test.csv_0_0_0.csv.gz | LOADED | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |  |  |  |  |

```
SELECT * FROM copy_to_test;
```

| SINGLE_STRING |
| --- |
| orange |